# How to enable input disabled by default if it has value when user goes back from browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I am developing a laravel app for buying tickets at an event. 
I have 2 input boxes disabled by default, and 2 checkboxes also disabled by default. You first need to check at least one checkbox which enables an inputbox to type in, then you can proceed to the next step by pressing a button and making a post request. The problem is:

If someone decides to press the back button from the browser (After submits the post request) the checkbox remains checked but the input box remains disabled, meaning that the value of it will be null (it stores the input from before).

This is the form on page refresh
[image: FORM IMAGE]

This is the form before submitting it
[image: FORM BEFORE SUBMIT]

This is the form after submitting it and going back without refreshing it again

[image: FORM AFTER SUBMIT AND COME BACK WITHOUT REFRESH]

If a user submits the form in the final screenshot, he will get an error because there is input in a disabled box but the box it is checked. When I will try to read the input because it is checked, I will get null.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <input type="checkbox" name="2_box" id="2_box">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-text">
            Jeton 2 &euro;
        </div>
        {{--<div class="input-group-text">--}}
            {{--Total: <span id="total_2" class="sum"></span>--}}
        {{--</div>--}}
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantitate" name="2_amount" id="2_amount" disabled>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            Total:  <span id="total_2" class="sum"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" name="10_box" id="10_box">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-text">
                Jeton 10&euro;
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantitate" name="10_amount" id="10_amount" disabled>
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                Total:  <span id="total_10" class="sum"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<script>
document.getElementById('2_box').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('2_amount').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('10_box').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('10_amount').disabled = !this.checked;
};
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#2_amount').change(function(){
        var total = 0;
        jQuery('#2_amount').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).val() != ''){
                total = parseInt(jQuery(this).val()) * 2;
            }
        });
        jQuery('#total_2').html(total);
    });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#10_amount').change(function(){
        var total = 0;
        jQuery('#10_amount').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).val() != ''){
                total = parseInt(jQuery(this).val()) * 10;
            }
        });
        jQuery('#total_10').html(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel [Old Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input). It was created specifically for saving information between requests. So, if the form fails for example.

Considering your scenario, though, you would basically just need to read the `old` for the input that should trigger the checkbox and enable/disable it.